# How can I pass association to changeset in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a pretty simple `Comment` model:

```
  schema "comments" do
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
    timestamps
  end
```

I want to create a new record and I want `changeset` that validates that user exists. How can I do that?

My ecto version is `1.1.8`.

Comment: Write a custom changeset and validate if the user_id is valid or not?

Comment: user id, can be present but it can be wrong. Something like user with id is not existing in the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to let the database handle data integrity. Writing a check for this in your application is prone to race conditions. What if a `User` is deleted between your validation and `Comment` insertion? What if a `User` with any existing `Comment`s is deleted? Handling this in the database will make sure you never have invalid data in your database.

First, make sure that the `user_id` field is set to `references(:users)`:

```
create table(:comments) do
  ...
  # Check out the various :on_delete options you can pass to here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2
  add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nilify_all)
end
```

then, in your `changeset` function, after piping to `cast`, add this:

```
|> Ecto.Changeset.assoc_constraint(:user)
```

This will convert errors related to `user_id` returned by the database into normal Changeset errors. You can read more about `Ecto.Changeset.assoc_constraint/3` [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#assoc_constraint/3). Also see [`Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3).

Comment: Yeah, this actually what I'm looking for. Thanks!